# Not able to set proper data position in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

***Scenario:***

I am fetching data from database and it's printing data in FPDF in a loop.

***Problem:***

I am facing problem with printing data in the loop in the left side of page. It has properly set all data but when I tried to put data on left side of page, then it automatically skips line on the right side of page.

***Question:***

I do not know why that happened; maybe there is problem with setting the position of `x` and `y`.

The following is my code:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
require ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('times','',8);
$sql = "SELECT address,user_id FROM contact
        LEFT JOIN address ON address.contact_id = contact.contact_id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $pdf->Cell(20,3,'Name : ');
    $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
    $string = str_replace(' ', '', $user_id);
    $pdf->MultiCell(64,3, $string,0); 
    $pdf -> SetX(110);
    $pdf->Cell(20,3,'Name : ');
    $user_id = $rows['user_id'];
    $string = str_replace(' ', '', $user_id);
    $pdf->MultiCell(64,3, $string,0); 
    $pdf->Cell(20,2,'Address :'); 
    $address = $rows['address'];
    $address = str_replace(' ', '', $address);
    $pdf->MultiCell(64,3, $address,0);
    $pdf -> SetX(110);
    $pdf->Cell(20,2,'Address : ');
    $address = $rows['address'];
    $address = str_replace(' ', '', $address);
    $pdf->MultiCell(64,3, $address,0);
    $pdf->Ln(); 
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

where I've issue to set the properly the data position. Any ideas?

Comment: Making `Cells` after `MultiCells` cause a kind of carriage return in the pdf. You should use `setY()` to correct this. But maybe it isn't your problem .. Can you give a screenshot of your problem ? I don't really get it

Comment: http://php.nxsolprojects.com/core/ashutosh/ashutosh/printaddress.php @tektiv in that url u can see that left side position of name is proper but right side name is go down..

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$user_id = $rows['user_id'];
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $user_id);
$pdf->MultiCell(64,3, $string,0); 
......
$myX = $pdf->GetX(); $myY = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetY($myY); $pdf->SetX($myX); 
....
pdf->Cell(20,3,'Name : ');
$user_id = $rows['user_id'];
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $user_id);
```